# JQuery slideToggle on a class

Tags: jquery

i have a problem with the slideToggle effect on my site.

I have assigned the effect to a class but when one link is clicked it is opening every content block which has that specific class.

Is there anyway that you can assign this effect to a class and have them open when each specific one is clicked.

Please view at the following url; http://www.presentationplayer.info

Note: Don't use Internet Explorer as the site has'nt been tested in the browser at the moment

Comment: FYI, your server has a misconfiguration.  Visiting www.presentationplayer.info redirects to /public_html, which results in a 404.  But visiting presentationplayer.info (no www) works.

Comment: Also, when asking a question that requires looking at some code, please try to use http://jsfiddle.net/, preferably with a simplified example of the site you're working on, rather than linking to your actual site.  That way others who find this question in the future can still benefit from this question and its answers even if your site changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code performs a slideToggle on everything that has the class `article_content`:

```
$('.article_content').slideToggle();
```

So what you need to do instead is traverse up in the hierarchy to find the parent article and then traverse down to the corresponding article content under it, then finally call `slideToggle` on that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.article_title a').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('article').find('.article_content').slideToggle();
        $(this).innerHTML = 'close';
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey Jeff .... Works perfect ... thanks for the quick response and sorry about any confusion caused